# Spring Security - Invalid column index exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to use spring security.But I'm getting SQLException.I still haven't found any solution.

**My table structures:**

APP_USER ( ID_APP_USER,NAME,PASSWORD )

APP_ROLE (ID_ROLE,NAME)

APP_USER_ROLE (ID_USER_ROLE ,ID_USER,ID_ROLE)

**My Spring configuration file :**

```
 <!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/index"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select name as username,password from app_user where name=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "SELECT app_user.name as username, app_role.name as role 
            FROM app_user 
            INNER JOIN app_user_role ON app_user.id_app_user = app_user_role.id_user 
            INNER JOIN app_role ON app_user_role.id_role = app_role.id_role
            WHERE app_user.name = ? " />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**And I'm getting following error :**

> 20:36:55.281 [http-nio-8089-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.j.s.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator - Translating SQLException with SQL state '99999', error code '17003', message [Invalid column index]; SQL was [select name as username,password from app_user where name=?] for task [PreparedStatementCallback]
>   20:36:55.282 [http-nio-8089-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [select name as username,password from app_user where name=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
>   20:36:55.282 [http-nio-8089-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
>   20:36:55.282 [http-nio-8089-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@2f483b1e
>   20:36:55.282 [http-nio-8089-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /login?error
>   20:36:55.282 [http-nio-8089-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/FNDWEB/login?error'

What's wrong ? please help me :/ Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found solution. We need to add "**,1 as enabled**" to our query.

```
<authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select name as username,password,1 as enabled from app_user where name=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "SELECT app_user.name as username, app_role.name as role 
            FROM app_user 
            INNER JOIN app_user_role ON app_user.id_app_user = app_user_role.id_user 
            INNER JOIN app_role ON app_user_role.id_role = app_role.id_role
            WHERE app_user.name = ? " />
  </authentication-provider>
```